# Nativescript does not recognize paths outside the app folder

Tags: angular, path, nativescript

I am trying to add Nativescript to existing Angular project. In the Angular project I have custom code in folders under *src*, but outside *app*. While Angular recognizes the paths just fine, Nativescript does not. Is there something I can set in Nativescript to process paths outside the *app* folder?

Comment: Try updating the `include` array with the paths to the external files / folders in `tsconfig.json`

Comment: Doesn't work. Nativescript follows the paths relative to it's own build that does not seem to include folders outside app.